# What's the definition of $\langle a,b\rangle$ in a group?

Tags: group-theory, definition

I know that a single-element generator is defined by $\langle a \rangle = \{a^k: k\in \mathbb{Z}\}$. But what is $\langle a,b\rangle$? Is it $\langle a,b\rangle = \{a^kb^j: k,j\in \mathbb{Z}\}$?

Comment: You say modulo ring, but you have tagged the question with group theory, but you're using powers of $a$ and $b$. Could you please be a bit more specific about the exact domain here? Are we talking groups or rings? Subgroups or ideals?

Comment: @Arthur sorry, I wanted to say group of units, specifically $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$. So I'd like to talk about groups.

Comment: @DietrichBurde OK, done.

Comment: Your group is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z/(p-1)\Bbb Z$, because $\phi(p)=p-1$. So it is cyclic of the form $\langle a \rangle$. So you don't need $\langle a,b\rangle$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde okay, and what if $p$ isn't prime? What does $\langle a,b \rangle$ mean then?

Comment: It means, that you need two generators. Indeed, $(\Bbb Z/8\Bbb Z)^{\times}\cong C_2 \times C_2$. So let $C_2=\langle a\rangle$ and the other $C_2=\langle b\rangle$. Then the group is $\langle a,b\rangle$.

Comment: In general, if $G$ is a group with elements $g_1, g_2, \dots, g_k,$ then $\langle g_1, g_2, \dots, g_k \rangle = \{g_1^{n_1} g_2^{n_2} \cdots g_k^{n_k} \,|\, n_i \in \mathbb Z \text{ for all } 1 \leq i \leq k\},$ i.e., the set of products of powers of the generators. For instance, each of the generators belongs to $\langle g_1, g_2, \dots, g_k \rangle$ as well as things like $g_1 g_2,$ $g_1^{-1} g_2^{-2} g_k^3,$ and the identity element of $G.$

Comment: @Carlo If the group isn't abelian, you need to amend that slightly.

Comment: Sure. Throw in that $g_i g_j = g_j g_i$ for all integers $1 \leq i < j \leq k.$

Answer (score 2):

Most of the time, $\langle a, b\rangle$ denotes the substructure generated by $a$ and $b$. Now, as pointed out by Arthur, it remains to know whether your current structure is a monoid, a group or a ring.

Comment: I'd like to have the definition for a group, specifically for $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$

Answer (score 2):

Given a subset $S$ of a group $G$, the subgroup generated by $S$ consists of the set of all products of the form
$$s_1^{\alpha_1}\cdots s_k^{\alpha_k}$$
where $s_1,\ldots, s_k$ are *not necessarily distinct* elements of $S$, and the $\alpha_i$ are integers.

In particular, if $S=\{a,b\}$, you'll have expressions of the form
$$a^{\alpha_1}b^{\beta_1}\cdots a^{\alpha_k} b^{\beta_k}$$
where the $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_j$ are integers, not necessarily nonzero. If you know $a$ and $b$ commute, then you can simplify this to expressions of the form $a^ib^j$ with $i$ and $j$ integers. They need not be all distinct (just like for a single element $a$, the elements $a^k$ need not be all distinct for different powers $k$).

Answer (score 2):

Given a group $G$ and a subset $S\subset G$, the *subgroup generated by $S$* is by definition the intersection of all subgroups $H\subset G$ such that $S\subset H$ and is denoted by $\langle S\rangle$. Since intersections of subgroups are subgroups, this is always a subgroup and by construction it is the smallest subgroup of $G$ containing all elements of $S$.

When $S$ is a finite set $S=\{s_1,\dots,s_k\}$ the generated subgroup $\langle S\rangle$ is just written as $\langle s_1,\dots,s_k\rangle$.

Hence, $\langle a,b\rangle$ is by definition the intersection of all subgroups of $G$ containing $a$ and $b$. As explained in Arturos answer, the elements of $\langle a,b\rangle$ can always be written as finite products of integral powers of $a$ and $b$ and when $G$ is abelian this simplifies to products $a^i b^j$ with $a,b\in\mathbb Z$.